# How do you take the inner product of a vector whose components have different units?

Tags: vector-spaces, unit-of-measure

How do you take the inner product of a vector whose components have different units?

For example, what is the inner product of $\langle1m, 1s\rangle$ and $\langle2m, 3s\rangle$?

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense. in mathematics, you don't have units. units are used only in physics

Comment: Should I post in the physics forum? Sorry, I am an engineer.

Comment: how did this question arise?

Comment: I don't think they will be able to help you. Make sure that you really want to do this. Mathematically, to get an answer you just ignore the units and do it. But it is not at all clear what the units of the result will be... I mean if you do it naively with your example, then you get $1m+3s$. what does this even mean!? think about this

Comment: No, the naive answer is $1m^2 + 3s^2$.

Comment: One idea I had, was that when dealing with vector spaces whose components have different units, yet you want to have an essentially euclidean concept of distance, you could define your inner product to normalize out the units, so that the final expression makes sense.  I think, although I am not 100% certain, that this is close to what @MarkFischler 's response is saying.  I need to do some background reading to really follow though.

Answer (score 2):

While one might (wrongly) think this question is meaningless, you can have a sensible meaning involving mixed-unit vectors as follows:

The inner product is always a bi-linear form where you have a vector and a *conjugate* vector (in linear algebra, a row vector and a column vector).  As such, you need a (linear) way to go from a vector to a vector in conjugate space. This "way" is what we think of as a metric tensor.

For your problem to make sense, the metric tensor has to have units.  This is not so strange; think of special relativity, where the metric tensor looks like
$$
g_{11} = g_{22} = g_{33} = 1; g_{44} = -c^2
$$
where $c$ is the speed of light (say in meters per second).

Then
$$
<1 \mbox{ m} , 1 \mbox{ s}> \cdot <2 \mbox{ m} , 3 \mbox{ s}> =
( 2 - 3 c^2\mbox{ s}^2) \mbox{ m}^2
$$

Comment: why are the units of the last expression m^2/s^2 and not m^2?

Comment: Because I cgoofed, I will correct that error.

Comment: And note that the Minkowski metric does not satisfy the non-negativity part of most inner-product definitions, but you can see that an analagous metric with signature $(++++)$ would still serve the same purpose for this issue.

Comment: What do you mean by wrongly? It certainly is meaningless. It is not even a proper mathematical question, and your answer is not really a mathematical one

Comment: @313 It's meaningful mathematically if one can impose any consistent interpretation. "I don't know a consistent interpretation, therefore it's meaningless" isn't a mathematical argument. Whether the proposed interpretation is consistent is a separate question; maybe it is, maybe it isn't, but you can't rule it out _a priori_.

Comment: @Mark-Fischler It should be $... =  2\mbox{ m}^2 - 3\mbox{ s}^2 c^2 $ c has dimensions so it "converts" seconds in meters. Or even better $...=  2\mbox{ m}^2 - 3\mbox{ s}^2 c^2 =  2\mbox{ m}^2 /(c^2) - 3\mbox{ s}^2$ because both options are valid depending if you want to have the result in m or s (similar to light-year).

Comment: @JoKalliauer I have made a correction to address your valid comment

Answer (score 1):

The set of lengths forms a one-dimensional real vector space $L$, and the set of durations forms a one dimensional real vector space $T$. It follows that the cartesian product $L\times T$ forms a two-dimensional real vector space $V$ in a natural way. A basis of $V$ is given, e.g., by the two vectors $e_1:=(1\,{\rm m},0)$ and $e_2:=(0,1\,{\rm sec})$.

A scalar product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ on $V$ is a bilinear function
$$B:\quad V\times V\to{\mathbb R},\qquad (x,y)\mapsto\langle x,y\rangle$$
satisfying certain axioms. In order to install such a product you have to prescribe the numbers
$$g_{ik}:=\langle e_i,e_k\rangle\in{\mathbb R}\qquad(i, k=1,2)\ .$$
This means that you have to prescribe  the values $$g_{11}=\langle(0,1\,{\rm m}),(0,1\,{\rm m})\rangle,\quad g_{12}=g_{21}=\langle(1\,{\rm m},0),(0,1\,{\rm sec})\rangle,\quad g_{22}=\langle(0,1\,{\rm sec}),(0,1\,{\rm sec})\rangle.$$
Whether this will lead to meaningful things depends on the application you have in mind.